# Post multiple values with file to server in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload

I had a requirement to post multiple variables along with the file to the server.. The variables are Username,Password,FileName and file itself.. The servers authenticates the user and uploads the file..

I found [HttpForm](http://procbits.com/2012/02/29/submittingposting-files-and-fields-to-an-http-form-using-c-net) class which does what I want.. I am uploading multiple files in the loop so it freezes the window until all files are uploaded.. so the problem is that I want asynchronous upload, basically I want to show the progress of file upload. How can I achieve this using this class? or is there any alternate available? I can't seem to find any.

Thanks

Jhon

Comment: You can use async await. here is a good implementation http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/drag-and-drop-files-to-wpf-application-and-asynchronously-upload-to-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Alternatively if you're new to async programming I would recommend the [BackGroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.80).aspx) class. It takes the sting out of async which can sometimes be complex.